# Row prepend in Jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I have an HTML data table, I attached code and also attached test case. Here I do dynamically prepend the row in data table,that means I want to add a row in first position with serial number dynamically. [Test Case Datatable](http://live.datatables.net/kibokupu/46/watch)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.5.2/css/colReorder.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.5.2/js/dataTables.colReorder.min.js"></script>  

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>   
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>S.No</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Salary.</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>1</td>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>2</td>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<input type="button" value="addNew Row" onclick="addNewRow()"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the JavaScript is:

```js
function addNewRow() {
  
        var table = $('#example').dataTable();
        var rowLen = table.fnGetData().length;
        var srNo = rowLen + 1;

        var t = $('#example').DataTable();
        t.row.add(['1','vuyv','54','89855']).node().id = 'lclSsrContainer_' + rowLen;
        t.draw(false);
        $('#lclSsrContainer_' + rowLen).attr('style', 'color: #0822f3;');

    }
```

How to add dynamically in first position with dynamic serial number, and no change in data table?

Comment: "_How to add dynamically in first position...?_" - By always sorting the data on column 1 (in descending order)?

Comment: It's not clear (to me) what you mean by "dynamic", since you have code which creates a new `srNo` (is that a serial number?) but you don't use it. Also, where is your DataTable defined? Why do you  create two table variables `var table` and `var t` in two different ways? What is the purpose of the `.node().id` code? Why is that included? Can you [edit] your question to clarify/simplify?

Comment: **.node().id** is  used to highlight the append row

Comment: i attched simple test case

Comment: Please provide the data needed to answer the question in the question, instead of linking to an external web site. And why not just sort the data to ensure the new row is displayed as the first row? That seems like a simple solution.

Comment: @andrewJames sorting is the simplest way to resolve this problem,But Logically I tried to refresh or decrease the count of serial no in  loop.

Comment: In Normal jQuery we can easily do it ***Prepend()*** method.How to use Prepend method in Datatable

Comment: DataTables does not have a `prepend()` function (you can [check the documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/)) - because it would be meaningless in the context of a DataTable - which is _not_ an HTML table. That's like asking for the "first" record in a relational database table. The data has to be explicitly sorted for "first" to be meaningful. (Otherwise, if your DataTable data is not sorted, then the default ordering of data is based on the order in which data was loaded into the DataTable. The last row to be loaded is the last row shown in the DataTable.)

Comment: "_I tried to refresh or decrease the count of serial no in loop._" - not sure what that means exactly, but again it sounds as if you would have to rely on sorting for that to be effective. And it sounds like a lot of unnecessary work, when there is a simpler approach.

Comment: Thanks @andrewJames ,After reading Datatable documents,sorting is easier and effective approach.

Comment: Good news - I am glad you have a solution. You are welcome to [write an answer to your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you want to - especially if you think it will be helpful to future visitors to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datatable has no property liked

***prepend()***

If we want to add a row in first postion it collapse our datatable functionalities,So finally after adding a row
`t.row.add([rowLen,'vuyv','54','89855']).node().id = 'demo_' + rowLen;`

just reorder the table as like

`$('.sorting_asc').click();`
this jquery function can solve my problem.It comes first position

Comment: yaha its working fine without errors.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

because your table is set to sort on "s.no" the row will be inserted based in this value so if you did :

```
t.row.add(['0','vuyv','54','89855']).node().id = 'lclSsrContainer_' + rowLen;
```

that would be placed in the first row because the "s.no" value is "0"  and if you wanted it at the end row every time:

```
t.row.add([rowLen,'vuyv','54','89855']).node().id = 'lclSsrContainer_' + rowLen;
```

the problem is though is if you waned "s.no" as any value and still be the first row you would have to remove the sort from the table

hope this helps

Comment: After appending row use  ***$('.sorting_asc').click()*** to get first position